# JAVA how to get the value on JTextfield

Tags: java

I would like someone to check this program I'm having trouble on getting the result, it wont display. I tried so many ways. please help I just started studying java. please help here's my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class Counter extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
JPanel row1 = new JPanel();
JLabel title = new JLabel("Monthly Total Sales");

JPanel row2 = new JPanel();
JLabel week1 = new JLabel("1st Week");
JTextField text1 = new JTextField(10);
JLabel week2 = new JLabel("2nd Week");
JTextField text2 = new JTextField(10);

JPanel row3 = new JPanel();
JLabel week3 = new JLabel("3rd Week");
JTextField text3 = new JTextField(10);
JLabel week4 = new JLabel("4th Week");
JTextField text4 = new JTextField(10);

JPanel row4 = new JPanel();
JLabel month = new JLabel("Monthly Total:");

JPanel row5 = new JPanel();
JButton count = new JButton("TOTAL");

public Counter()
{
    super("Monthly Earnings");
    setSize(500,500);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);

    Container pane = getContentPane();
    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(5,1,2,2);
    pane.setLayout(layout);

    FlowLayout layout1 = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,2,2);
    row1.setLayout(layout1);
    row1.add(title);
    pane.add(row1);

    GridLayout layout2 = new GridLayout(1,2,2,2);
    row2.setLayout(layout2);
    row2.add(week1);
    row2.add(text1);
    row2.add(week2);
    row2.add(text2);
    pane.add(row2);

    GridLayout layout3 = new GridLayout(1,2,2,2);
    row3.setLayout(layout3);
    row3.add(week3);
    row3.add(text3);
    row3.add(week4);
    row3.add(text4);
    pane.add(row3);

    FlowLayout layout4 = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,2,2);
    row4.setLayout(layout4);
    row4.add(month);
    pane.add(row4);

    FlowLayout layout5 = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,2,2);
    row5.setLayout(layout5);
    row5.add(count);
    pane.add(row5);

        setContentPane(pane);
    setVisible(true);

}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent tot)
{
    if(tot.getSource()==count)
    {
        float we1=0;
        we1 = Float.parseFloat(text1.getText());
        float we2=0;
        we2 = Float.parseFloat(text2.getText());
        float we3=0; 
        we3 = Float.parseFloat(text3.getText());
        float we4=0; 
        we4 = Float.parseFloat(text4.getText());

        float total = (we1+we2+we3+we4);
        month.setText("Php"+total);

    }

}
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Counter counting = new Counter();

}
   }
```

having problem on displaying the result.. :(

Comment: Do you have a question? What's happening? What's going wrong?

Comment: What is the result and where should it display? Please be more clear and try to minimize the example.

Comment: im trying to display the result. but it wont work..

Comment: There's no "result" in the code and we're not mind-readers.

Comment: after clicking the button, the total should be the sum of values input on the text fields and it should be displayed right next to this: JLabel month = new JLabel("Monthly Total:");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register the ActionListener with your button for the `actionPerformed` method to be invoked

```
count.addActionListener(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply do not add the ActionListener anywhere, so nothing will happen when you hit the "TOTAL" Button.

Answer (score 1):

to get the text in the textfield assign a string to name of textfield -
    .getText();